# Extract original name & date from m2ts (mpeg2-ts) files

Tags: node.js, video-processing, mpeg2-ts

I want to extract the original name and date-taken from m2ts files in Node.
I found some dead code (m2ts-parser) using the package "packet". Though I'm too novice to really understand. But I want to learn :-)

So can anyone tell me how to extract the original filename and original creation date of the m2ts file (in node, but any pseudo code will do :-)

Thanks

**update**

I found - based on the answer of @aergistal a partial solution.
I am able to extract the Date/Time original from an m2ts file. Tested only on a Canon and Panasonic file:

```
var fs = require('fs');


fs.open('C:/temp/28685338476.mts', 'r', function (status, fd) {
    if (status) {
        console.log(status.message);
        return;
    }
    var chunk = new Buffer(10000);
    var syncFound = false;
    var i, l;
    fs.read(fd, chunk, 0, 10000, 0, function (err, num) {

        for (i = 0, l = chunk.length; i < l; i++) {

            if (chunk[i] === 0x47) {
                syncFound = true;
            }

            if (syncFound) {
                if (chunk[i] === 0x66 && chunk[i + 1] === 0x4D && chunk[i + 2] === 0x44 && chunk[i + 3] === 0x50 && chunk[i + 4] === 0x4D) {
                    console.log("GOT 'MDPM' at byte ", i);
                    var yy = chunk[i + 8].toString(16) + chunk[i + 9].toString(16);
                    var MM = chunk[i + 10].toString(16);
                    var dd = chunk[i + 12].toString(16);
                    var hh = chunk[i + 13].toString(16);
                    var mm = chunk[i + 14].toString(16);
                    var ss = chunk[i + 15].toString(16);
                    var timeStamp = yy + "/" + MM + "/" + dd + " " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
                    console.log("TimeStamp: "+  timeStamp);
                    return timeStamp;
                }

            }


        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such information in the MPEG-TS container.

This kind of metadata *might* be included in one of the elementary streams in which case its location will be different for every stream type. To make things worse there's no common standard even for the same type.

For example if your `m2ts` file contains a `H.264` video stream such metadata *might* be found within the **Supplemental Enhancement Information** (`SEI`) if provided. The structure is described in the H.264 standard.

Once you know where the data is you will need to find out what format it uses. One example is the **Modified Digital Video Pack Metadata** (`MDPM`) which is supported by the [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/H264.html) and *might* contain a `DateTimeOriginal` tag. [Example](http://hirntier.blogspot.fr/2009/08/avchd-timecodes-revealed.html).

Of course, the metadata might not be present at all or stored in an auxiliary file.